# How to convert Bitmap to Base64 String

Tags: android, bitmap, base64

I am developing an android application which uploads `Base64` String of image into web server. Therefore, I have used the following code to convert a Bitmap into `Base64` String.

```
public String getEncoded64ImageStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteFormat = stream.toByteArray();
    String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP);
    return imgString;
}
```

For example, I need to convert this [***image***](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1SdoM.png).
After the conversion, I'm not getting the `Base64` String as I expected.

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAIcAAAB7CAYAAABet5NoAAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAB/FJREFUeJzt3U1a4lgXB/D/uVQps3IBNuoKZEg56fQKml6BqRU0NdDXITWrBwbtDhp3oDuAicUQVoBYLkBmSndy3gHEDkgggZvkJjm/kR8hXPP8Pbk55IOQkJHVOCi97lnMqBJxFUwHAH4NWp6AMQMPAB4YeFBQ3V/637tJjTcuT2cXVYfJUqBjZq4CqAL4tOFlPRA/M9Mgye1Aca786eyiyqxsZrYAnGpabY8Jty6r25P+9wdN64zV4+fLOhh1AHVsDkJYsW8H7eEY1a6OFVxbATYDR7rXv6QHcKfSb3difp/IRrWr4xLcJvQGYjXiO4A6lR+tW62r1bUi38Y417XOsGa7IG6aEJKftSuLZ9shcJcZF93bYedwjKzGwYfX/SYz/6ljQLsgYMyEhu7/oDDS/OdYRsAYUPauc5OdwjHfl3YQd9mMrudA2UnNSca1yyYBDZi2HYjvnP1/7JPu9fNWL9/mRbMjj48dMP2+zesTMgG4EeeuZl4tbqFvsh2HCUHVt6kikcPxdHZRZZduE5hs6nLjlKeNbf97ghhcNVdi4NtRv9WM8ppI4XisXdgAXSMjG8Rn6JSnlq6AjD9fNojxl451Jeym0m/ZYRcOHY55MP7eZkQmIGBMiuuH9+3BLut5rF12YMCkcwc9pzyth/lHUWHWlvVgAAADR65L3aezi+q268hBMADg19LLXjfMghvDkYdg+HzaNiA5CYbndP73rLU2HLONSNfahmSGT+zS7chqHIR9Qc6C4Tkf1y6b6xYInHOMrMbBh5e9QYaOSqIKNUnNaTD+Q/gjqGkYWDlKrx87OQ4GAJxu2vfmPhgAwOgEVdGV4Zgdwxvd4NIlcN9biGDMfCq9fuys+sW73crIahyUXvYekL1exi4Wjv8LFIw3BPXbchf1XeX48LrfRLGCAQDns6OyYgZjxu0s/2Shcsw/KxglNh7z9JDCR+3m4C/+z6IWKsf8I+ciK3AwAAI1/d+/hWM+Y60nPSBhDgaOftauLO/7t3Co1z0bxZtriCUM1/a+fgsHMexVC4vCOff6Hgrw2uRGn7AiElR6+VgH5uFwmKxURyMMM8uDAgBimYiKBXVg3ud4rF1yumMRpnGgTpT/0EUIT4ncqnLJ3frMKJFfzKgqBTpOeRzCQARYan6ltxDLDhQBx2mPQhjpVOX8bC+xg1CXJohiknCIQBIOEUjCIQJJOEQgCYcIJOEQgSQcIpACMEl7EMJMCsBONzMR+SW7FRFIMdBNexDCTAoErXfZE/mhFCuZc4h3CBirf8svEg7xDgMP6qR7/Ty7V7YQ/yGigQIAJpbqIRYwu/NwMEk4xAKlMAuHguqmPBZhlsnhfXsWjjw8O01oRNwFFjukvXRGIozDuAV84ZBOqfA4KHUBXzhKihN/9JUw0tB7wtVbOA7v2wPpdwgmdLyvFz+VJZLqUXDu/rTjfb0QDqL3NyoVhXLjf1DAQjjmTzEaJj4kYQSC6vi/X3GyD+ft+SoinN7Ge59X+u2OTEyLiDvLP1l5miCDm3EPRRhluOr5uyvDIdWjWAiqserngScYS/UojHdzDU9gOOZlRo5ccs6BsoN+t/bShKByI/KBgW9eq3yVjU+k/vn5f9fM/KfWUQkTDCv91tqbBW68qOnf/demTE7zRym2Ny6zaYGT7vUzKZZ7o+cIE77Ou+Frhboc8vC+PWDg2+7DEqkjvjv60QrVBQ99rexRv9UE8d32oxIGGDr7/9hhF450IfV8xXJ4m00Tpdje9Hh2v41HK8uezi6qrktdyPPgsmSiFFth5hl+kW/BcHjfHijFVtTXiRQR7KjBALa8P8fsjfjLNq8VSeMvlR+trc7wi7xb8Zs94pv+3mUdIk6LT5iOaqdwABIQc+0WDEBDOAAJiHl2DwagKRyABMQQWx2VBNEWDkACkjKtwQA0302w0m93QPgDcm/TpGkPBqC5cnikUZaoWIIBxHQfUl+jTCpIvIZxBQOIqXJ4RlbjoPSy1wVwGuf7FNTQKU+tKJ+VRBVrOAAJSExiDwaQwO2tT7rXz055agG4ifu9CoH4LolgAAlUDr/H2mUHwHmS75kzN5V+y07qzRK9MX6l37LljLKtJRoMIOHK4ZFmWVR62uFRpfJIjdkfyl8gh7ohpBMMIKXK4ZFm2VoTgqqneRvQVMMBSEACxNb1jCL1JzUd3rcHTnl6DDlx2TN0oKppBwMwoHJ4pFkGIKHmVlipVw6PNMtwY1IwAIMqh18Bm2WJ9zDCMKZy+FX6LZsJX9MeRxKY8NXEYACGVg5P/ptl6fUwwjA6HADws3ZlMdxb5OtQdwKCve31JEkxPhxA7nohRvQwwjByzrHs8L49cKCqyH4vJNYzt3TLROXwZLwXYlQPI4xMVA5PhnshvawFA8hY5fDLUC/EyB5GGJmqHH4Z6YVkNhhAhiuHx9xeiNk9jDAyHw7AxF5I9oMB5CQcgDG9kNRP0NEps3OOZQb0QiZKsZWXYAA5CgcAnPS/P8wPdZMOSKaaW2HlKhxAKr2QoVOe5i4YQI7mHKsk0AvpOeVpPWvNrbByHQ4AGH++bBDjrxhWnekeRhi5DwcQSy8k98EAChIOQGcvJB89jDAKEw5ARy+kOMEAcni0ss4OvZAJQf1WpGAABascnojnhWTmzC3dClU5PBF6IcZcfZaGQlYOvzW9kMyduaVbISuH38rzQhK8tZLJCl85PL5eSCF6GGH8H2WNU29+inIcAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC
```

The real Base64 String it should be this (I use this [***website***](https://www.base64-image.de/) to convert)

```
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
```

What is the problem in my conversion ?
Thank you !

Comment: There's no problem with your conversion. You're running it through an additional compression step, which most likely accounts for the difference.

Comment: try to change  bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); as may be from their compressions it make some diff,

Comment: I have already try to use Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG. But the result in android base64 string is different with the website conversion.

Comment: Hi @SinLok, did you get some solution? I get the same error ...

Answer (score 11):

```
public static String encodeTobase64(Bitmap image) {
    Bitmap immagex = image;
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    return imageEncoded;
}

public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input) {
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
}
```

Comment: My code is similar with you. I cannot convert the bitmap into a corresponding base64 string.

Comment: No, your code is not same as my code. Your code is String imgString = Base64.encodeToString(byteFormat, Base64.NO_WRAP); and I have changed it to String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT); You have used Base64.No_WRAP, but it is Base64.DEFAULT in my code.

Comment: Oh I see, but I copy your code to use. And find that the Base64 string is similar Base64.NO_WRAP. Only the different is Base64 string is not in single line. However, using Base64.DEFAULT to produce Base64 string is not same with real Base64 string.

Sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: I used this code but I had trouble decrypting it from bitmap to bitmap

Comment: @alimazaheri What issue you are facing? To decrypt, you must need to pass string value in a given function.

Answer (score 1):

```
public String getBase64ImageString(Bitmap photo) {
        String imgString;
        if(photo != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outputStream);
            byte[] profileImage = outputStream.toByteArray();

            imgString = Base64.encodeToString(profileImage,
                    Base64.NO_WRAP);
        }else{
            imgString = "";
        }

        return imgString;
    }
```

Pass your Bitmap in the parameters you will get your image string.